# Serialize custom block with InnerBlock

Tags: block-editor

I have a custom gutenberg block with arbitrary InnerBlocks. For reasons of a custom javascript library I am using I cannot use the `<InnerBlocks>` component but want to iterate over all blocks and display the blocks with their InnerBlocks in my block's edit function.

I want to write a slider block with the [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) library. My efforts to really make the InnerBlocks (with Toolbars and other UI) work did not work out well. First, swiper needs a special DOM structure, that I could not get with the `InnerBlocks` component as it has a predifined wrapper and div structure. Second, swiper clones slides when you loop it, which eventually caused react errors when the whole gutenberg block ui was cloned. So what I figured out to work best is to have a button in my block, that switches between "edit mode" and "preview mode", where you see the `InnerBlocks` with all the UI for adding, moving in edit, and where you see the slider in preview mode.

I am using the code (simplified):

```
{ innerBlocks.map( ( block ) => {
    return (
        <div
            key={ block.clientId }
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: wp.blocks.getBlockContent( block ) } }
        >
        </div>
    );
} ) }
```

This works for most innerBlocks like `core/heading`, `core/paragraph`, ... But for embeds e.g. it just displays the embed url but not the embedded media content, e.g. from Youtube. I found `wp.blocks.serialize` and `wp.blocks.rawHandler` but cannot get it to work either. What am I doing wrong.

I am looking for answers that make embeds work without `<InnerBlocks>` or for a solution that works with swiper (loop enabled) and `<InnerBlocks>`.

Comment: This won't work as those blocks won't be interactive or have their hooks fire. You'll also get their saved content rather than their edit components. This approach is a dead end. Can you share your original problem? There's a good chance that your problem can be either solved, or sidestepped, or that a misunderstanding has been made and you can achieve your goal by other means. Additionally, expand your code example to include the entire component

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for the answer, I extended my question. I do not mind that being a "dead end" in that way the user cannot edit blocks anymore, because as I described I have that edit mode available. My problem is really just the hooks(?) not being fired if that is what makes embeds work and I wonder how that would be possible. It is also a "dynamic block" with a php frontend, but I figured it was way faster and more performant to not use a `<ServerSideRender>` in edit, or would that be the only way?

Comment: I do not believe that is true, that library has react support https://swiperjs.com/react/ all you need to do is wrap the innerblocks component in a `<Swiper>` component, then wrap the children in `<SwiperSlide>` components. You can do this easily with a Swiper block and a Swiper Slide block, much like how core has a columns and a column block. Do that and your problem and all the workarounds and hacks disappear into thin air, it even provides a nice way to add new slides as you can make sure an inserter is always showing, and your inner blocks are always editable live

Comment: @TomJNowell I tried that and alot of other approaches. The Problem with what you suggest is, that if I do `<Swiper><InnerBlocks></Swiper>` where all inner blocks are wrapped in `<SwiperSlide>`, the innerblocks add two wrapper divs which make swiper unusable. Also I tried the new `useInnerBlocksProps` hook, to get rid of the wrapper divs however then the parent `<Swiper>` does not recognize it  `SwiperSlides`. For me it ends up in trying it the way I am asking for above.

Comment: If each inner block is a slide then that is not the appropriate method of doing that. You cannot have just a swiper block, you need a swiper slide block, as well as a prop to restrict the inner blocks to only be swiper slide blocks, in the same way that the columns block doesn't just wrap the contents, it instead has individual column blocks. This can not and should not be done with a single block

Comment: That is what I did. The columns / column block are my blueprint to the degree I explained. All I need is the rendered save content that works for all blocks, especially embeds.

Comment: Can you expand your code example? I can't see how you're retrieving `innerBlocks`, there's no way to reproduce without figuring everything out from scratch

Comment: I've gotten about 99% of the way there, but I'm missing a vital piece of information that you already have but did not share. ***How did you get the `innerBlocks` array?*** If I had that array I could fix my answer to be fully feature complete

Comment: So I figured that part out and it was a dead end. What you've asked is extremely difficult to do, and my final conclusion is that it is not possible because f how the library itself works. A rival carousel library would have been ***significantly*** easier to implement.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to use the slider library in the block's **edit** method as well, not only on **save**, right?

Comment: @kero Yes. The *save* is working, edit as wellAnd I am wondering if `<ServerSideRender>` could be my friend here. @TomJNowell in [`withSelect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/#withSelect) I do: `const innerBlocks = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks( clientId );` It can then be filtered for only slide blocks.

Answer (score 6):

What you asked for is not possible for blocks that rely on frontend javascript, this includes embeds.

---

It's also not possible using the Swiper react library. The Swiper library made the questionable choice of manually inspecting child components for the `SwiperSlide` component name, preventing it from ever being used with child blocks.

***Edit:** **Actually maybe it is!** Since writing this, [a PR was merged that may fix this and allow the code below to work as desired](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/pull/4144#event-4272738115)*

---

It isn't possible using jQuery either with inner blocks as it conflicts with the way React works, and will cause virtual DOM problems.

#### The Closest You Can Get

Instead, if we use the React Swiper library, `useBlockProps`,  and `useInnerBlocksProps`,  we can implement this, and have editable slides, while keeping the slider.

However, Swiper will not see the specific arrangement of components it needs and will place them after the slider container instead of inside the wrapper.

The important thing to note, is this snippet:

```
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps( blockProps, {
            allowedBlocks: [ 'tomjn/swiper-slide' ],
            template: TEMPLATE,
        });
        const params = {...};
        return (
            <div { ...innerBlocksProps }>
                <Swiper { ...params }>
                    { innerBlocksProps.children }
                </Swiper>
            </div>
        );
```

By using `innerBlocksProps.children` we eliminate the 2 containing `<div>` tags.

Here's my demo:

*`src/index.js`*:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import {
    InnerBlocks,
    useBlockProps,
    __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps as useInnerBlocksProps
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';

// install Swiper components
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

const TEMPLATE = [
    [ 'tomjn/swiper-slide', {}, [
        [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Enter slide content...' } ],
    ] ],
    [ 'tomjn/swiper-slide', {}, [
        [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Enter slide content...' } ],
    ] ]
];

registerBlockType( 'tomjn/swiper', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Swiper',
    category: 'layout',
    edit: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps( blockProps, {
            allowedBlocks: [ 'tomjn/swiper-slide' ],
            template: TEMPLATE,
        });
        const params = {
            init: true,
            paceBetween: 50,
            slidesPerView: 2,
            loop: true,
            navigation: {
                clickable: true,
            },
            spaceBetween: 30,
            pagination: {
                clickable: true,
            }
        };
        return (
            <div { ...innerBlocksProps }>
                <Swiper { ...params }>
                    { innerBlocksProps.children }
                </Swiper>
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        return (
            <div className="swiper-container">
                <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                    <InnerBlocks.Content />
                </div>
                <div className="swiper-pagination"></div>
                <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );

registerBlockType( 'tomjn/swiper-slide', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Swiper Slide',
    category: 'layout',
    edit: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        return (
            <SwiperSlide>
                <div {...blockProps}>
                    <InnerBlocks />
                </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        return (
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

*`package.json`*:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "swiper": "^6.4.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wordpress/scripts": "^12.6.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build",
        "check-engines": "wp-scripts check-engines",
        "check-licenses": "wp-scripts check-licenses",
        "format:js": "wp-scripts format-js",
        "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
        "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
        "lint:md:docs": "wp-scripts lint-md-docs",
        "lint:md:js": "wp-scripts lint-md-js",
        "lint:pkg-json": "wp-scripts lint-pkg-json",
        "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
        "start": "wp-scripts start",
        "test:e2e": "wp-scripts test-e2e",
        "test:unit": "wp-scripts test-unit-js"
    }
}
```

*`plugin.php`*:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Toms Swiper Plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://tomjn.com
 * Description: Swiper no swiping.
 * Requires at least: 5.5
 * Requires PHP: 7.3
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Tom J Nowell
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

add_action(
    'enqueue_block_editor_assets',
    function() {
        $asset = include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php';

        wp_register_script(
            'tomjn-swiper-block-js',
            plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
            $asset['dependencies'],
            $asset['version'],
        );
        wp_register_style(
            'tomjn-swiper-block-css',
            plugins_url( 'build/index.css', __FILE__ ),
            [],
            $asset['version'],
        );
    }
);

/**
 * Registers all block assets so that they can be enqueued through Gutenberg in
 * the corresponding context.
 */
function tomjn_swiper_register_block() {

    if ( ! function_exists( 'register_block_type' ) ) {
        // Gutenberg is not active.
        return;
    }

    register_block_type(
        'tomjn/swiper',
        [
            'editor_script' => 'tomjn-swiper-block-js',
            'editor_style'  => 'tomjn-swiper-block-css',
        ]
    );
    register_block_type(
        'tomjn/swiperslide',
        [
            'editor_script' => 'tomjn-swiper-block-js',
            'editor_style'  => 'tomjn-swiper-block-css',
        ]
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'tomjn_swiper_register_block' );
```

Comment: A bit more digging shows that the swiper carousels are... awful. It's directly manipulating child components which is a terrible thing to do in order to get the slides in an array, even though there are far better ways like react context to do this. Ironically, what I need to figure this out is the very part of your question you did not add to try and be helpful

Comment: So I figured that out and it didn't lead anywhere good. React Swiper will not accept it as a slide, and there is no way to get the final HTML that appears on the frontend because that HTML is not what the user sees once JS has finished running ( embeds for example are converted into their final form on the frontend ). The fundamental problem is the choice f this library and its poor design choices in its React component. Specifically https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/react/get-children.js#L13-L25

Comment: As for the original method that was asked about, it is not possible for blocks that have a frontend JS component, such as embeds. You can show their edit components but then you run into issues leading you to the code that's in my answer ( individual edit components would not be possible as they would no longer be attached to the document )

Comment: Thanks Tom, for all the effort you already put in this. I also looked in that swiper file you posted above already and altered it, so that it "always" pushes to the slides array. This got me somewhere at least. However still having other issue on that path. `innerBlocksProps` really seems to get me as close as possible. My question really was if there was a way with the `save` output of the blocks and it is at least satisfiying to find it is a dead end (and not put more time in it). I think I somewhere read about using `innerBlockProps` in class components but cannot find it. Do you know?

Comment: `innerBlockProps` is meant to let you put the block component props on to your edit components markup rather than it being wrapped, the goal in Gutenberg core is to make styling blocks in the admin closer to the frontend, and to reduce the `<div>` spam to improve performance. I don't believe there's a class based version but its internals can be reused. I did look to see if the get children function could be monkey-patched, and I raised a ticket suggesting they use React context instead https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4084

Comment: If you're asking so that you can use `ref`'s and reuse the jQuery implementation, the issue there is the dom cloning and the way it collects the slides into an array and then constructs its children, so the slider doesn't really have _children_ per say, the markup is more configuration than structural in use which is why we've been sent on a wild goose chase :)

Comment: I suspect this library may sidestep all of those issues though https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper but it requires a little extra work for previous/next buttons etc, could the React children issue be a Swwiper v6 specific issue?

Comment: I have the impresion that react-id-swiper will die sooner or later because of the official swiper react version. I would not build on it now. Cool that you raised issues, i guess that is the proper way of doing things. Which I had the time to even submit a pull request. I will keep you updated on the way I solved things finally.

Comment: @user9 behold! https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/pull/4144 I believe this fixes the edge case of swiper slides wrapped in higher order components, you may now be able to proceed using the React swiper slider components using the main branch, or the next release

Comment: wow, i am impressed. cool. i will check it out tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: your demo does not work unfortunately. The slides content is not editable. No sliding works. Did you test it? For me it fails unfortunately.

Comment: ah that's unfortunate :(